# SAS9.3 PROC FCMP can not save user defined function

Tags: sas, proc, fcmp

I want to use proc fcmp to define my own function in SAS9.3.
OS is aix 64bit.
Here is my code (reg_func.sas):

```
proc fcmp outlib=mylib.funcs.rule;
function gen_sub_rule();
put "this is a test function";
return (0);
endsub;
run;
quit;
```

but after run sas reg_func.sas, i got some warnings

[WARNING:Cannot wirte model to data set mylib.funcs because it is curently opened or already exists as a standart data set.Will revert to V8 CATALOG instread.
WARNING:Failed to save function gen_sub_rule to mylib.funcs.rule.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfTrE.png)

Can anyone help?Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a different outlib option?

Comment: @Reeza, Thanks, I tried this way,  add [libname mylib '/home/ap/sas/mydir';] before my proc fcmp code. and it works. but there is another problem.,when i use deletefunc, sas tells this waning:SUBROUTINE 'GEN_SUB_RULE' cannot be found for deletion.

Comment: Post how you tried to delete it. Without seeing code only assumption is you did something wrong :)

Comment: @Reeza, Here is my delete code:`proc fcmp outlib=mylib.funcs.rule; deletefunc gen_sub_rule;run;quit;`

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Is your function actually deleted?

Comment: @Reeza, No, my function wasn't deleted.it still exists in `mylib.funcs.rule`.i think ith's kind of strange that sas can't find my funcion.Maybe there is something wrong with my sas configuration, i changed my plan to use macro in my proj. thanks ,it's very kind of you of answering my question.

Comment: You should post it on communities.sas.com, someone way more knowledgeable than me will answer it.

Comment: @Reeza, Yeah, i will try that, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Referrring to [https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Irritating-warning-in-Proc-FCMP/td-p/16216](http://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Irritating-warning-in-Proc-FCMP/td-p/16216) 
The key is the cmplib option, here is my code:

```
    libname mylib 'H:\saslib\testlib';
    proc fcmp outlib=mylib.funcs.rule;
      function calc(var);
         newvar=log(var);
         return(newvar);
      endsub;
     function gen_str(var1 $, var2 $, var3 $) $100;
        length newvar $100;
        newvar=catx('#', var1, var2, var3);
        return(newvar);
      endsub;
    Run;

    /*list the source code*/
    Options cmplib=_null_; 
    proc fcmp library=mylib.funcs;
      listfunc calc gen_str;
      run;
    Quit;

    /*using func*/
    options cmplib=mylib.funcs; 
      data _null_;
        numret=calc(20);
       charret=gen_str('what', 'is', 'your');
       put numret= charret=;
    run;

    /*delete the func*/
    options cmplib=mylib.funcs; 
    proc fcmp outlib=mylib.funcs.rule;
    deletefunc calc;
    run;
    quit;
```